# Can you use Next.js with a React Native App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

I have recently been learning Next.js for React and I like the routing system a lot more than react navigation. Now I am about to start a react native frontend and I was wondering if you can utilise Next.js's routing system in react native as well as it's other benefits. I know that you can use it with expo but I am a little confused as to how it all works and I am starting to wonder if the Next only works on the web side of things..

Does anyone have any experience with this? Any information would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to use it in React Native. Next.js sole purpose is to enable server-side rendering for a web page coded with React, while React Native makes programs for mobile phones, where there is no concept of "server", "client" or even web pages.

Comment: @Alejandro not because main objective of NextJs was SSR doesn't mean you can't combine them to concentrate your effort in a single code system, where you can reuse like 80% of your codes for all plaftforms. The only drawback is that is that config is tough if you don't know how to do it yet, and also you have to separate navigation with a nav and link adapter `.web` that use next router and link, and `.native` that use react navigation and link. I know because I did it, and already in staging, waiting for production soon.

Comment: @Alejandro there is a use case for this - when you want to have shared universal components that are imported into a) next.js to be rendered by web browsers; and b) expo to be rendered by ios and android. The next.js can be used to do the routing - SSR is one excellent reason to use next.js, but that does no mean you don't want to share some of your underlying components with you mobile app stack..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do such thing, due to the fact that the views of react native are Equivalent to native views in Java or Objective C. When you get build version of react native , you are receiving Java or Objective C native views thank to react native's **RN bridge**. Meanwhile, when you get build version of your Next.js project, you are going to receive HTML, CSS, JS and these codes are not familiar to native platforms.

However, you can use your Next.js backend as your endpoints and fetch data in react native via calling this endpoints.

**UPDATE Oct_2022:**

there seem to be a new tool created for this purpose , called [solito](https://solito.dev/). I haven't used it personally but it might meet your needs.

**UPDATE Jan_2023:**

It looks like there are more Tools being created for Both web and native platforms , check [react-native-web](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/)

Comment: This is not true anymore, with the use of `react-native-web`, it's certainly ready to use with `expo` already. Check out https://solito.dev

Comment: Actually since beginning of 2022, I was struggling to make an hybrid with RN and Next engines, specially in the configs. Now it works perfectly, only that you need to separate the Navigation system to use Router for web and React-Navigation for Native. I'm about to launch the Website and App soon, I'm just finishing the Unit Testing and Integration Testing before choosing the best way for me to deploy them.

Answer (score 8):

You can check out [Tauri](https://tauri.app). With that you can create from Next.js, React, Svelte etc. cross-platform native Apps. Currently, Windows, Mac and Linux are supported stable. Android & iOS is currently in [Alpha](https://tauri.app/blog/2022/12/09/tauri-mobile-alpha/)

The magic behind Tauri is, that they provide around your Frontend library/framework a Rust layer with that you can interact with platform native APIs. They call it [Commands](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command/).

You can find the guide for Next.js [here](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/getting-started/setup/next-js/).

Also, if it's not exactly answering the question - "Is it possible to use Next.js in **React native**?" - I hope that it's helping everyone who is searching for a solution to use Next.js as Cross-Platform Frontend Framework

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of support now for this tech stack. Besides [solito](https://solito.dev/), which is already mentioned, there is also https://tamagui.dev/ which tries to solve all the issues with react-native-web and Next.js along with Solito.

While they currently recommend a monorepo (which adds a lot of complexity in my opinion), I'm playing around with a vanilla React Native + Next.js here:

https://github.com/LunatiqueCoder/luna

This command should get you started to play around:

```
npx react-native init MyAppName --template @criszz77/luna
```

**EDIT:**

Now with Expo support!

`yarn create luna-app`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I read a thread on ycombinator on this where Solito was mentioned and tried it out. In the comments I found this, which suited my needs best :

https://github.com/mlynch/nextjs-tailwind-ionic-capacitor-starter

Solito looks nice but the all in one repo was using Expo, which I did not like because it installs an extra app. I would check it out for yourself and look at the repo above too, which is using Capacitor and is aimed at having one codebase for the two apps.

Both examples worked well. For Tauri I could not find the mobile support so I didn't try it. I would be interested to read more about people's experience with running a minimum stack for cross platform development.

Note : Solito uses React Native, the repo uses Capacitor instead, which may also suite your needs because it works on both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, now EXPO has support for nextjs. Visit the following documentation

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-nextjs/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out the EXPO router. It has many of the same file system routing principles as next.js.

https://docs.expo.dev/routing/introduction/